# What does this reference notation signify?

Tags: c++

On pg. 149 of *Jumping into C++*, the author states:

> In general, you should not store memory that you just allocated in a reference:
>
> ```
> int &val = *(new int);
> ```
>
> The reason is that a reference does not provide immediate access to the raw memory address. You can get it using & , but generally references should provide an additional name for a variable, not storage for dynamically allocated memory.

What does this mean on the right-hand side of the reference intialization?

I understand the notation of declaring (and immediately initializing) a reference as follows:

```
int x = 1;
int &ref = x;
```

But I don't understand what `*(new int)` refers to in the passage. And whatever it means, is it illegal to do this, or just a bad practice?

Comment: oode "int &val = *(new int);" - not good - memory in the wings

Comment: What does `*` mean, and what does `new int` mean, and what do brackets do?

Comment: @immibis: `*` in this context is the dereference ("indirection") operator. `new int` dynamically allocates an object of type `int`. Brackets do lots of things but here they disambiguate the complex expression. HTH

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are not in the target audience for that question.

Comment: @immibis: No need to be so rude.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you misquoted it. It's `*(new int)` and it means the same as any other `*<some pointer here>` — it dereferences the pointer.

It's the same as this:

```
int* x = new int;
int& ref = *x;
```

with `*x` of course being the expression that refers to the dynamically-allocated `int` object. Thing is, your way you don't have a variable name `x` to play with and now must write `delete &ref` at some point, which is just kinda weird.

Avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, technically it's not a bright idea, but of course you can later fix the mess like

```
int &val = *(new int);
val = 5;
delete &val;
```

If it was a class... and you dont want to use the -> operator, you could of course use this trick, as long as you remember to delete &val;, because after all, you have allocated something and needs proper clean up.

Comment: But you wouldn't. You'd write `{ auto ptr = std::make_unique<int>(); { int& ref = *ptr; ref = 5; } }`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you wouldnt do *(new int); at the first place either. None's talking about best code here I'd say, just about *(new int) and how you can use it.

Comment: but you're recommending an alternative and you have a duty of care

Comment: Isn't that what I did? I told him to remember to delete &val, since it's still memory allocated. There's my "duty of care". He isn't asking about smart pointers, or I'd use smart pointers too.

Comment: this might not work if you did it with a class with an overloaded address-of operator.  you would need to use std::addressof.